# Hiding a friend completely on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I would like to hide a friend completely on Facebook without blocking. This means that I don't want to see any updates about the person, the person's name won't show up in autocompletion, and I cannot access the person's Facebook profile page, without the person knowing anything is done on my side.

I have checked out [the chrome extension "Eternal Sunshine"](https://chrome.Google.com/webstore/detail/feekljflolojpmfccnopoppafimmmlbg), which comes very close to my needs, but I strongly want to have no access to the Facebook profile page/no name shows up in autocompletion.

I believe this can be done by js/jquery, but as I am still a novice on that, it'll be better if there's an existing extension having this function already. May I know if any such extension is currently available?

Answer (score 1):

what you are talking about is called - un subscribing from your friend's feed.

1. Login to your facebook account
2. Go to your friend's page and you will unsubscribe button. Just click on the buttona nd you will have the option to choose from - Unsubscribe from all posts, subscribe to important feeds only, subscribe to all feeds. Just choose unscribe and you will not see any more feeds.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the extensions I have seen, you will have to make your own. This isn't something widely requested.

Consider browsing other pages and profiles that have similar starting letters in their names. This should push that friend out of the autocomplete list. The maximum objects that display for autocomplete seem to be 8. So browse 8 objects (pages, friends, games) to push your friend out of that top 8 list.